# Modify rows of multiple data.table files

Tags: r, dplyr, data.table, tidyverse

I have two datasets `dt1` and `dt2`:

```
N = 100
dt1 <- data.table(x = rnorm(N), y=rnorm(N))
dt2 <- data.table(x = rnorm(N), z=rnorm(N))
list_dt <- list(dt1 = dt1, dt2 = dt2)
```

If `y` and `z` are negative, they are forced to be `0`. I implement it by this:

```
naming <- c("y","z")
for (i in seq_along(naming)){
   list_dt[[i]] <- setDT( list_dt[[i]] )[ noquote(naming[i]) < 0, noquote(naming[i]) := 0  ] 
}
```

But it's not working. I see the problem may be owing to the function `noquote()`, but I don't know why. Any advice is appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `lapply` :

```
library(data.table)

naming <- c("y","z")

lapply(list_dt, function(x) {
  cols <- intersect(names(x), naming)
  x[get(cols) < 0, (cols) := 0]
})
```

Answer (score 2):

```
lapply(list_dt,
       function(.x){
         .x[, lapply(.SD,
                     function(x) fifelse(x<0, 0, x)) , 
            by = "x"]     
       }
)
```

Answer (score 2):

Based on your code, it can be corrected as

```
naming <- c("y","z")
for (i in seq_along(naming)){
     list_dt[[i]][,noquote(naming[i]) := 
                   fifelse(get(naming[i]) < 0, 0, get(naming[i]))] 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

An option using `dplyr` and `purrr` could be:

```
map(.x = list_dt, 
    ~ .x %>%
     mutate(across(any_of(c("y", "z")), ~ pmax(., 0))))
```